# Cannot edit Area 51 proposals

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, user-interface, edits

When I click the edit link on an Area 51 proposal.

[image: screenshow]

Happens in Google Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fixed now.  We broke it with some other jQuery changes.